# I get the error "(psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL: role "wsb" does not exist", but the user does exits

Tags: postgresql, python, docker, sqlalchemy, bash

I am trying connect to my postgress database using SQLAlchemy. I was working fine yesterday (01/27/22). Now I get the following error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL:  role "wsb" does not exist

Only the user does exist.

```
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 wsb       | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
 wsb2      |                                                            | {}
```

As you can see I tried making another user "wsb2", but that didn't work either.
Below is my script:

```
db_string = "postgresql://wsb:wsb@localhost:5432/wsb"

db = create_engine(db_string)
meta = MetaData()

submissions_table = Table('wsb_submissions', meta,
                          Column('index', INTEGER),
                          Column('submission_id', TEXT),
                          Column('title', TEXT),
                          Column('created', TIMESTAMP),
                          Column('author', TEXT),
                          Column('ticker_mentioned', TEXT),
                          Column('subreddit', TEXT),
                          Column('emotes', ARRAY(TEXT)),
                          Column('rocket_emotes', INTEGER)
                          )

comments_table = Table('wsb_comments', meta,
                       Column('index', INTEGER),
                       Column('comment_id', INTEGER),
                       Column('body', TEXT),
                       Column('created', TIMESTAMP),
                       Column('author', TEXT),
                       Column('rocket_emotes', INTEGER),
                       Column('subreddit', TEXT),
                       Column('emotes', ARRAY(TEXT)),
                       Column('submission_key', TEXT)
                       )
db.connect()
```

also here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres:13.2

ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD=wsb
ENV POSTGRES_USER=wsb
ENV POSTGRES_DB=wsb

COPY wsb.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
EXPOSE 5432
```

Answer (score -1):

So this worked for me. I am relatively new to operating systems, so idk if there are any consequences that I'm unaware of.

my solution:
in terminal run:

```
lsof -i:5432
sudo kill [PID]
```

then rebuild the image and restart the container.

Comment: Thanks for the input. What would have been the better way? And how can I snuff out data corruption?

Comment: You are in no danger if you never use `kill -9` on the postmaster. Plain old `kill` is the right thing - it will shut down PostgreSQL properly. If you fix that, I'll un-downvote your answer, but the way it is it is a public danger. The best solution would of course to figure out what is going on.

Comment: ok, I'll change it. thanks for the clarification.